# Angular Material md-card-header background

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I am developing a small AngularJS application using angular-material. The problem is I cannot figure out how to properly set the background-color of the `md-card-header` using the color palette defined in my config.

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('blue')
    .accentPalette('pink');
```

Basically I want to set the primary color as the background color of the card header. I could of course copy the RGB value, create a class and set the color using this class. However, I would loose the benefit of changing the theme at runtime or at least I would have to manually change the color whenever I change my theme.

How can I set md-colors to any element, especially the md-card-header?

Answer (score 5):

You can not color backgrounds in angular-material as of yet. For your example I would work around this by using a `md-toolbar`. You can use `class="md-warn/md-primary/md-accent"`to style it with the colors from your palette.

```
<md-card>
  <md-toolbar class="md-warn" style="border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0">
    <md-card-header>
      <md-card-avatar>
        <img class="md-user-avatar" src="...">
        </md-card-avatar>
        <md-card-header-text>
          <span class="md-title">User</span>
          <span class="md-subhead">subhead</span>
        </md-card-header-text>
      </md-card-header>
    </md-toolbar>
```

**Update:**

Angular-material just added a [color service and a directive](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/colors) to use the colors defined in a theme anywhere in your code (1.1.0-rc4).

You can now do `<md-card-header md-colors="::{backgroundColor: 'default-primary-700'}">`.

I updated the codepen.

http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/pygvyR

Comment: check https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCard      Card is built with: point . can not add md-toolbar inside md-card

Comment: What a shame. Well, then I have to use a custom class to color the card header.

Comment: @ktn Of course you can add it, same way you can add `md-button` and most other directives. It may not be meant to be used that way, but it is the only workaround available at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

check https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/02_declarative_syntax

Theming in angular material apply to this

- md-button
- md-checkbox
- md-progress-circular
- md-progress-linear
- md-radio-button
- md-slider
- md-switch
- md-tabs
- md-text-float
- md-toolbar